Laravel(10) Dusk Login Test Failing
I have a fresh install of Dusk and I am trying to build a Login test. Here's where I started:
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use App\Models\User;
use Spatie\Permission\Contracts\Role;


beforeEach(function () {
    $this->user = User::factory()->create([
        'email'    => 'blueshoon@blueshoon.net',
        'password' => Hash::make('password'),
    ]);

    $role = app(Role::class)->findOrCreate('User', 'web');

    $this->user->assignRole($role);
});

test('user login', function () {

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {

        $browser->visit('/')
            ->type('email', $this->user->email)
            ->type('password', 'password')
            ->click('button[type="submit"]')
            ->assertPathIs('/dashboard');
    });
});


it always fails that this user isn't found. I have created a dusk .env file and created a
separate db for dusk. When I comment out use LazilyRefreshDatabase; from my Dusk Test Case class I see that this user is being created in the db and checking my Authenticate Controller, it's has the correct credentials. Any help as to how to debug this would be great.

are you sure the .env is configured correctly so the code makes the user and can authenthicate it

my .env.dusk.local is a copy of my normal working .env with the database pointing to the test version.
